# I cannot access a component from its own gameobject (unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-components

I want to access the HorizontalAxis variable from the CarAgent component (of the Taxi gameobject).
It works fine when I try to access it from another gameobject, but when I try to access it in CarUserControl, which is also a Taxi component, it says that CarAgent doesn't exist.

This is the other gameobject's script and it works fine:

```
private float HorizontalAxis;

public void Start() {

     HorizontalAxis = GameObject.Find("Taxi").GetComponent<CarAgent>().HorizontalAxis;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{

    transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, HorizontalAxis, 360);

}
```

and this is the CarUserControl script:

```
 private void Start()
    {
        HorizontalAxis = GameObject.Find("Taxi").GetComponent<CarAgent>().HorizontalAxis;
}
```

How can I access the HorizontalAxis variable in CarUserControl ?

EDIT: I tried to access other classes in this script and it doesn't work neither.
I got this script from the UnityStandardAssets/Vehicules/Car, so at the beginning, it is written:

```
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car
{
[RequireComponent(typeof (CarController))]
public class CarUserControl : MonoBehaviour
{
```

I am new to unity and c# so does it change something. And if yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: The first works because you're getting the object before getting the component: `GameObject.Find("Taxi")`. The second code snippet tries to get CarAgent from the same GameObject, without doing `GameObject.Find("Taxi")` first.

Comment: @Maakep exactly ... but that is supposed to work .. that's why the OP asks here...

Comment: Are you 100% sure both components are on the same root level GameObject and not somehow nested?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah but the only answer is that OP is, like you're writing here^, trying to GetComponent on a GameObject that doesn't have the GameObject. It could be that OP has accidently added this script on another GameObject while thinking it's the correct one malfunctioning. I suggest searching for the class name in the hierarchy, which will highlight all objects with the script attached. Or, if added dynamically, add a `Debug.Log(gameObject.name);` in the Start() of CarUserControl to verify which objects are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem was that the CarUserControl was in the standard assets folder and that the CarAgent script was not in that folder. Apparently, the standard assets folder does not compilate at the same time as other folders. See more [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1019558/how-to-access-public-variable-in-namespace.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that you are too low or too high in the gameobject chain.

Try

```
car = GetComponent<CarAgent>(this.parent);
```

OR

```
car = GetComponent<CarAgent>(this.child);
h = car.HorizontalAxis;
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is in the parentheses please?

Comment: "this" refers to the current gameobject, in your case its the CarUserControl

Comment: Yes but what is it doing when you put it in the parentheses?

Comment: You are passing the current gameobject parent or child into the GetComponent Method.

Comment: it returns Type `UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car.CarUserControl' does not contain a definition for `parent' and no extension method `parent' of type `UnityStandardAssets.Vehicles.Car.CarUserControl' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: I need to see more code to be able to say. please provide more information

Comment: @KelsoSharp can you show me where you found a typed `GetComponent<type>()` implementation that takes a parameter? Also note that there is no `this.parent` .. you probably mean `this.transform.parent` which is of type `Transform` but yet there is no implementation taking that as parameter

Comment: Just a quick correction here, to avoid potential confusion; `this` is actually the MonoBehaviour component; the class you're writing it in. `this.gameObject` (or, for short, `gameObject`) is the gameObject.

Comment: You probably mean `GetComponentInChildren<type>(true);` or `GetComponentInParent<type>();`

Comment: I edited the question, so could you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly because there are inconsistencies between the `Update()` (every frame) and the `FixedUpdate()` (every physics frame). Indeed a `FixedUpdate` can be called more than once for the same `Update()` frame, or not at all.

Unity's doc about [Order of Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) explains it more.

Also, querying `GetComponent<T>` in loops is quite heavy. It is wiser to "cache" the reference in an `Init` method like `Start()` or `Awake()`.

```
private HorizontalAxis hAxis;

public void Start(){
    GameObject taxi = GameObject.Find("Taxi");
    if(taxi != null){ 
        hAxis = taxi.GetComponent<CarAgent>().HorizontalAxis;
    }
}

public void Update(){
   if(hAxis != null)
     transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, hAxis, 360);
}

public void FixedUpdate(){
    if(hAxis != null){
        // Do only Physics related stuff: rigidbodies, raycast
        // inputs and transform operations should stay in the Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, so could you take a look please?